# Is it possible to call the "exit" command every time I exit terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

How can I tell terminal to call the "exit" command automatically when I exit the terminal?

I am running Ubuntu Unity and using the default terminal program. I want to call "exit" before exiting terminal because, if I do not, then a certain process does not quit.

Comment: Which certain process? How do you exit, by clicking the _x_ or with Ctrl+D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean you want the shell running in the terminal to call a function before exit. In that case use `trap`, try this:

```
trap 'echo Hey' INT
```

Now send an interrupt signal to yourself:

```
kill -INT $$
```

Instead of `echo Hey` you can call an arbitrary function.